# How to draw a polygon with Sceneform, ARCore?

Tags: java, android, polygon, arcore, sceneform

Let's say I have three anchors from hit result from ArFragment.

> Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();

How can I draw a triangle and apply custom texture using Sceneform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step is to create a list of `AnchorNode`s to be able to get the coordinates of the `Anchor`s. We will add all of them in a list:

```
private final List<AnchorNode> anchorsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then in `OnTapArPlaneListener`, we can create our triangle if we reach three anchors (or three coordinates). We will generate our triangle as a `ModelRenderable`:

```
final Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
final AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
anchorsList.add(anchorNode);

if (anchorsList.size() == 3) {
    final Texture.Sampler sampler = Texture.Sampler.builder()
            .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
            .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
            .setWrapModeR(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .setWrapModeS(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .setWrapModeT(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .build();

    Texture.builder()
            .setSource(() -> getAssets().open("wall.jpg"))
            .setSampler(sampler)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(texture -> MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(this, texture)
                    .thenAccept(material -> {
                        final Node node = new Node();
                        final ModelRenderable triangle = makeTriangleWithAnchors(anchorsList, material);

                        node.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                        node.setRenderable(triangle);
                    })
            );
}
```

and here is the detail of the method `makeTriangleWithAnchors()`:

```
private ModelRenderable makeTriangleWithAnchors(@NonNull final List<AnchorNode> anchorNodes, @NonNull final Material material) {
    if (anchorNodes.size() != 3) throw new IllegalStateException("Different count of anchorsList than 3");

    final Vector3 p0 = anchorNodes.get(0).getLocalPosition();
    final Vector3 p1 = anchorNodes.get(1).getLocalPosition();
    final Vector3 p2 = anchorNodes.get(2).getLocalPosition();
    final Vector3 up = Vector3.up();
    final UvCoordinate uvTop = new UvCoordinate(0.5f, 1.0f);
    final UvCoordinate uvBotLeft = new UvCoordinate(0.0f, 0.0f);
    final UvCoordinate uvBotRight = new UvCoordinate(1.0f, 0.0f);
    final List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            Vertex.builder().setPosition(p0).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uvTop).build(),
            Vertex.builder().setPosition(p1).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uvBotRight).build(),
            Vertex.builder().setPosition(p2).setNormal(up).setUvCoordinate(uvBotLeft).build()
    ));

    final List<Integer> triangleIndices = new ArrayList<>(3);
    triangleIndices.add(0);
    triangleIndices.add(2);
    triangleIndices.add(1);
    triangleIndices.add(0);
    triangleIndices.add(1);
    triangleIndices.add(2);

    final RenderableDefinition.Submesh submesh = RenderableDefinition.Submesh.builder()
            .setTriangleIndices(triangleIndices)
            .setMaterial(material)
            .build();
    final RenderableDefinition renderableDefinition = RenderableDefinition.builder()
            .setVertices(vertices)
            .setSubmeshes(Arrays.asList(submesh))
            .build();
    final CompletableFuture future = ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(renderableDefinition)
            .build();

    final ModelRenderable result;
    try {
        result = (ModelRenderable) future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("Error creating renderable.", e);
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("Error creating renderable.");
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the result I got with the code shown before (I added some Bugdroids to show where the anchors are):
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wish they post more stuff/examples like this in their doc reference and add support for more geometric primitives besides sphere, cube, cylinder.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I took a look at how the cube is implemented in the `ShapeFactory` to adapt it for a flat triangle. Finally, that's would be great if you mark my answer as the solution to your question.

Comment: Can yoy please help modifying the code to set one of the nodes as a parent for the created triangle?
When `arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene()` is set - the nodes-triangle connection is less stable. But when I just change the parent - the triangle appears smaller and shifted.
Thank you for help!

Comment: @Wang Your example is great! Do you know how to rotate the texture? And is it possible to zoom in/out the texture? Thanks a lot!