# How to draw a polygon with texture in Sceneform/ARCore?

Tags: android, textures, polygon, arcore, sceneview

How can I draw custom texture/material inside a defined polygon (defined by 3 or 4 or more points)?

I found this: [How to draw a polygon with Sceneform, ARCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433707/how-to-draw-a-polygon-with-sceneform-arcore)

It's a good start. But it's only for 3 points. What if the user adds 4th point? I tried to update the code but it always draw texture as a triangle.

Next, I found this: [Sceneform applying textures to triangle seamlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099206/sceneform-applying-textures-to-triangle-seamlessly) (it's similar problem to mine)

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

I'm using SceneView in my app https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android

Also, it's possible to rotate and zoom in/out the texture?

Thanks for the info!